# Problem with rotation of an AR object with Vuforia

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm facing issues with the rotation of an object, I'm using Unity and Vuforia. I have a kinematic chain (it's a robotic arm) and I want to control his movement. I have a Remote Controller which sends a string with angular position for each link of the robot. I decode the string and then  assign final position for each link. I'm using slerp to modify the local rotations.
When I try this code without Vuforia, the code works well and the links rotate, but when I use Vuforia and the chain is above the marker, I can make the links rotate but then all of them come to their original position. I don't know why I have this behaviour.

This is the code I am working, I've tried also updating the position of each link, but I suppose I don't need that because I am working with local angles. I am receiving data through TCP/IP.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using TMPro;


public class MyListener : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int connectionPort = 25001;
    TcpListener listener;
    string[] stringArray;
    float[] Objetivo;  
    float[] posInicial;
    float[] currAngle;
    string msg;
    public Transform[] Link = new Transform[6];
    Quaternion[] startRotation = new Quaternion[6];
    Quaternion[] currentRotation = new Quaternion[6];
    Quaternion[] smoothRotation = new Quaternion[6];
    Quaternion[] endRotation = new Quaternion[6];


    int flagGiro, remoto;   
    public int flag;
    float duration = 3f;

    public TMP_Text Text1;
    public TMP_Text Text2;
    public TMP_Text Text3;
    public TMP_Text Text4;
    public TMP_Text Text5;
    public TMP_Text Text6;

    void Start()
    {
        flagGiro = 0;
        flag=0;
        remoto = 0;
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, connectionPort);
        listener.Start();
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
            startRotation[i] = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
   
    void Update()
    {
        if (!listener.Pending()){
            flag=0; 
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Link[i].localRotation = endRotation[i]; 
            }
            if (remoto==1)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    Link[i].localRotation = endRotation[i];
                }
                
            }
            } 
        else {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns);
            msg = reader.ReadToEnd();
            stringArray = ParseData(msg);            
            Text1.text = stringArray[0];
            Text2.text = stringArray[1];
            Text3.text = stringArray[2];
            Text4.text = stringArray[3];
            Text5.text = stringArray[4];
            Text6.text = stringArray[5];
            //x,y,z también pueden ser un array
            float y = float.Parse(stringArray[0]);
            float x = float.Parse(stringArray[1]);
            float x1 = float.Parse(stringArray[2]);
            float y1 = float.Parse(stringArray[3]);
            float z = float.Parse(stringArray[4]);
            float x3 = float.Parse(stringArray[5]);

            endRotation[0] = Quaternion.Euler(Link[0].localEulerAngles.x, y, Link[0].localEulerAngles.z); //endRotation[0] = Quaternion.Euler(0, y/div, 0);
            endRotation[1] = Quaternion.Euler(x, Link[1].localEulerAngles.y, Link[1].localEulerAngles.z);
            endRotation[2] = Quaternion.Euler(x1, Link[2].localEulerAngles.y, Link[2].localEulerAngles.z);
            endRotation[3] = Quaternion.Euler(Link[3].localEulerAngles.x, y1, Link[3].localEulerAngles.z);
            endRotation[4] = Quaternion.Euler(Link[4].localEulerAngles.x, Link[4].localEulerAngles.y, z);
            endRotation[5] = Quaternion.Euler(x3, Link[5].localEulerAngles.y, Link[5].localEulerAngles.z); 

            // Obtener las rotaciones iniciales de los objetos secundarios
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                startRotation[i] = Link[i].localRotation;
            } 
                StartCoroutine(RotateObject(duration));
            }
    }

    public static string[] ParseData(string dataString)
    {
        Debug.Log(dataString);
        if (dataString[0]==':'){
            dataString = dataString.Remove(dataString.Length-4);
            dataString = dataString.Substring(1);       
        }
        // Split the elements into an array
        string[] stringArray = dataString.Split('/');
        return stringArray;
    }
    
IEnumerator RotateObject(float duration)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        startRotation[i] = Link[i].localRotation;
    }
    
    float elapsedTime = 0f;
    while (elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            smoothRotation[i] = Quaternion.Slerp(startRotation[i], endRotation[i], elapsedTime / duration);
            Link[i].localRotation = smoothRotation[i];
        }
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Link[i].localRotation = endRotation[i]; 
        Vector3 endPosition = Link[i].localPosition;
        Link[i].localPosition = endPosition;
    }
    remoto = 1;

}
}
```

I appreciate your collaboration. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since your marker is most probably not at (0, 0, 0) or at the same position as your remote controller assumes the robot to be, the local rotations cannot be correct. You can verify this by placing your marker in Unity at the matching robot origin. As you said yourself, everythings moves back to their "original" position.

What you need to do is to convert your rotations into your marker coordinate system. If your position really is irrelvant, you can convert your quaternions only. If you need further input for that, take a look at this [quaternionToLocal](https://forum.unity.com/threads/convert-world-space-rotation-to-local-space-rotation.332025/).

Generally, I would suggest using rotation matrices especially in the context of kinematic chains of robots. With these (homogeneous) transformation matrices conversion between coordinates systems reduces to simple multiplication.

I hope the idea is clear. Let me know if you need any further information:)

Comment: As you said, I should place the robot matching the marker. Finally, the problem was that I had something like a race condition, other class was modifying the robot angles. Thank you for your response!